# cakephp: Fatal error: Class 'appModel' not found

Tags: cakephp-2.0

In my localhost (with xammp) CakePHP works fine. After I completed my project and uploaded to my host, it gives me this error:

```
cakephp: Fatal error: Class 'appModel' not found in .../app/Model/Slider.php
```

Model class was called in AppController and AppModel.php (App::uses('appModel', 'Model')) & all is fine in my localhost!

When I am trying to change php version, it gives me the same error, but in php 5.2 doesn't show anything but error, in php5.3, php5.4 and php5.5 it give me the error in the layout (call menus, footer... etc all but data !!

My CakePHP version 2.5.2
I don't do any change or coding inside AppModel and I think that I don't do any change in lib files or something like that.

what is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Insert following line at top of the Slider.php:

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
```

and start slider model as follows:

```
class Slider extends AppModel {

...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have deleted AppModel.php from app/Model folder